# postgis calculate volume for pyramid

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Is it possible to compute the volume for pyramid> in postgis

[image]

```
SELECT 
    ST_Volume(ST_MakeSolid(geom)) 
  FROM (SELECT 'POLYHEDRALSURFACE
        ( 
            ((0 0 0, 0 1 0 , 1 0 0, 0 0 0)),
            ((0 0 0, 0 0 1, 0 1 0, 0 0 0)),
            ((0 0 0, 1 0 0, 0 0 1, 0 0 0)),
            ((1 0 0, 0 0 1, 0 1 0, 1 0 0))
        )
    ') As f(geom);
```

My error:

> NOTICE:  During volume(A) : NOTICE:    with A: SOLID((((0/1 0/1
> 0/1,0/1 1/1 0/1,1/1 0/1 0/1,0/1 0/1 0/1)),((0/1 0/1 0/1,0/1 0/1
> 1/1,0/1 1/1 0/1,0/1 0/1 0/1)),((0/1 0/1 0/1,1/1 0/1 0/1,0/1 0/1
> 1/1,0/1 0/1 0/1)),((1/1 0/1 0/1,0/1 0/1 1/1,0/1 1/1 0/1,1/1 0/1
> 0/1))))
>
> ERROR:  Solid is invalid : PolyhedralSurface (shell) 0 is invalid: not
> connected : SOLID((((0/1 0/1 0/1,0/1 1/1 0/1,1/1 0/1 0/1,0/1 0/1
> 0/1)),((0/1 0/1 0/1,0/1 0/1 1/1,0/1 1/1 0/1,0/1 0/1 0/1)),((0/1 0/1
> 0/1,1/1 0/1 0/1,0/1 0/1 1/1,0/1 0/1 0/1)),((1/1 0/1 0/1,0/1 0/1
> 1/1,0/1 1/1 0/1,1/1 0/1 0/1)))) SQL state: XX000